# Removing the Apache TomCat runtime from a project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've got a project I've been building on Eclipse Ganymede targetted at tomcat 6.0, I've imported it into Europa and I need it to run on apache Tomcat 5.5

I can't find the reference to where the runtime is set to 6.0 to remove it. I've tried going to Windows > preferences > Server and I've installed the 5.5 runtime.

I can't however seem to find where the reference is to runtime 6.0 to remove it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I cant find any reference to Tomcat v6.0 in my build path, there is a reference to the servlet-api.jar of tomcat 5.5 though...

Comment: When you create a Web project, you select a Runtime and Eclipse adds it to your Build Path. If it isn't there, something went wrong with the importing.

Answer (score 29):

When Eclipse is up and running, choose preferences from the window menu. Choose from the bar on the left: Server, Runtime Environments.

Click the button Add, choose the version you want.

To remove the 6.0 reference, goto the libraries tab.

Comment: I've added the 5.5 runtime I want, however my project apparently requires tomcat 6.0 and I'm trying to remove this requirement.

Comment: I +1 this because it helped me solve my problem, but it seems the last part is a little vague.  The OP said he was trying to remove 6.0 - so it seems that should be the most important part.  Where is the 'libraries' tab and what should he do when he goes to it?

Answer (score 10):

You can delete a Runtime easily from here, with no mess up:

Windows->Preferences->Server->Runtime Enviroments

Comment: works some of time (on centos), but not all the time ;)

Comment: This helps me when i want to remove old  server location

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. I had a prject referring to a no more existing Tomcat instance.
I was not able to remove Tomcat from "Server" and "Runtime Environments" from UI (delete button always gray),so I solved the problem deleting all the reference from the filesystem:

In project folder check files:

- .classpath
- .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

In workspace folder check:

- .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core
- .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core
- .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs

Maybe a bit brutal but I didn't find a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

First, open the eclipse preferences,

[image: eclipse preferences]

then find the sever runtime environments,

[image: eclipse sever runtime environments]

you can now delete as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Unloading the project and reloading it fixed it... Man I love Eclipse...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But, I kinda disapprove that you love Eclipse. Its a bloated complex piece of enterprise mediocrity.

Comment: I know there isn't standardised notation for sarcasm on the Internet, but I thought the ellipsis made it fairly abundantly clear that I was being sarcastic.

Comment: ah, I dont generally associate ellipsis with sarcasm. A wink or smiley  maybe.

Answer (score 2):

This was tested over Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings. delete the following two files:

- org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
- org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs

Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Delete the old server and add a new server. I had the same problem due to the fact that i changed the runtime environment to Java EE (for a webservice) and later had problems running my local apps. All i did was to delete and create a new server instance with apache runtime.

Answer (score 1):

after removing the installed runtime from eclipse, do the following:

```
1] Close Eclipse

2] In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings. delete the following two files:
    org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
    org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs

3] Restart Eclipse
```

ref: http://crunchify.com/eclipse-how-to-fix-installing-apache-tomcat-server-issue-blank-server-name-field/

Answer (score 0):

Open the Build Path and go to the Libraries tab. Remove the Apache Tomcat 6.0 library and add 5.5. This is the library that your project uses to build it self.

You can add new runtimes for running your project in the Servers view (Right-Click, Add new Server)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just define a new server for that, and specify it there, also you can change server configuration just by double clicking on it you will see window with it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I have eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2; Build id: 20120216-1857, unfortunately deleting the workspace solve the problem with having old Target Runtime. Don't forget to copy all your project work if there is no source control ;) ....